# Class to Struct causing reassigning of variable not to work

Tags: swift

sorry to bother with something that is probably pretty easy.

Here is my code now the only difference is instead of 'struct' it was a 'class'. Now it's causing the changeAmount function to no longer work. I have tried declaring it as 'let' etc, but it shows other errors. If anyone has a fix that would be great.

```
struct Product {
    var ID : String = ""
    var name : String = ""
    var type : String = ""
    var price : Double = 0.00
    var image : String = ""
    var amount : Int = 1
    var imageURL : String = ""
    var thumbnailURL : String = ""
    var description : String = ""

    init(id:String, name:String, description:String, type:String, price:Double, image:String, imageURL:String, thumbnailURL:String, amount:Int = 1) {
        self.ID = id
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.type = type
        self.price = price
        self.image = image
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL
        self.amount = amount
    }

    func changeAmount(a:Int){ self.amount = a }
}
```

Comment: (Actually the same question was asked, answered, and closed as a duplicate just 30 minutes ago :)

Comment: Sorry! I wasn't sure how exactly to phase the question.! Mutating tag seems to have worked, thanks as always guys!

Comment: Can anyone explain why `mutating` I'd like to learn why exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function will change the contents of a struct, you need to declare it as `mutating`:

```
mutating func changeAmount(a:Int){
    self.amount = a
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why `mutating`?